# Change path of iframe on page change

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, iframe

I have two websites www.mywebsite.com and www.otherwebsite.com. I use iframe to redirect mywebsite.com to otherwebsite.com. Is there a to change the path of url on page change. For example when a link otherwebsite.com/contact.html is clicked the frame adds /contact.html to mywebsite.com making it www.mywebsite.com/contact.html. I tried adding the code below to the page but it doesn't seem to work on the frame.

```
history.pushState(null, "A new title!", "contact.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

what you trying to do is not possible without a server side language (for example php).

this is because you need to define filename as a variable for your frame to load it with another site.

but you can do it at some static way like making the real contact.html and code it with a frame that shows contact.html for another side ... but i dont think that would be a dynamic way without any server side coding...